# SlidingPaneLayout でスマートフォンとタブレットで挙動を統一させたいにゃ

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

例えばこんな感じに `SlidingPaneLayout` で[マルチペインレイアウト](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html)を作るとするでしょ

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

これをスマートフォンで見たら、左側のペイン( `@id/left` ) を開いたときに右側のペイン( `@id/right` ) が 操作(スクロールやタッチ)できなくなるよね ( [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) を開いたときみたいな)

でもタブレットで見たときは右ペインが操作できるんだ
凛はタブレットのときも操作不能にさせたいんだにゃ
つまり[Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)みたいにしたいにゃ

そこで、左ペインの `layout_width` を変える以外に操作不能にさせる方法を教えてほしいにゃ

Comment: [こちらで議論されました.](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1649/%E3%83%8D%E3%82%B3%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%9E%E5%B0%BE%E3%82%92%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E4%BD%93-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B) *編集行為が投稿者アカウントのアイデンティティ破壊につながる* ことや、表現の自由のためにも検閲のようなことは行わないとしています。

Comment: @natsukitinyak 「表現の自由」「検閲」といった単語は上記の議論では出ておらず，まとめとしてはやや不穏当ではないでしょうか．

Answer (score 5):

[Exploring SlidingPaneLayout](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/exploring-slidingpanelayout/)を参考に、
自分なりに下記のアレンジを致しましたのでご参照ください。

layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/SlidingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/covered"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#CC00FF00"
        android:text="Pane 1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
        <!--背景を、フェードしたい色であらかじめ設定する-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hidden"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#CC0000FF"
            android:text="Pane 2" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Activity.javaの一部

```
SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener panelListener = new SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener(){

    @Override
    public void onPanelClosed(View arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelOpened(View arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {
        //arg1には0~1が入るらしい
        //https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener.html#onPanelSlide(android.view.View, float)
        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)arg0;
        View childView = frameLayout.getChildAt(0);
        dimCustomChildView(childView, arg1);
    }

    private void dimCustomChildView(View v, float mag){
        // メソッド名はSlidingPaneLayoutのソースコードを参考にした
        // https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.java#L967
        // 上記メソッドでalpha値とかbit演算とかしてfadeの条件を決めたりどーのこーのとした結果、landscapeの時
        // fadeを止めてるっぽいのだけれど、なるほど分からん。setAlphaを持ち出しました。
        // どなたか、解説してください!!
        if (mag > 0 && mag <= 1) {
            v.setAlpha(1 - mag);
        }
    }
};
```

以上、よろしく御願いいたします。

Comment: ごめんね。
凛の質問が悪かったにゃ。
やりたかったのは「SlidingPaneLayoutの挙動をスマートフォンとタブレットで統一する」だったんだ。
例に挙げたレイアウトをスマートフォンで動かすと、左ペインを開いたときに右ペインを操作(スクロールやタッチ)しても反応しなくなるんだにゃ。
この挙動を"fade"と表現したんだけど間違ってたにゃ。
でも、おじさんのコードもこれはこれで使えそうだから使わせてもらうにゃ。
回答ありがとう!